# Verifying JSON schema for uri and string together?

Tags: json, jsonschema, web-api-testing

I am verifying below JSON schema for two separate JSON response which are same but only one difference is one returns 'system' as a string in format of uri and other returns plain string which cause failing of my second test case because for the second response it also look for a string in uri format.
How can i solve this issue in my schema?

```
{
  "id": "/coding",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "system": {
        "type": "string"
        "format": "uri"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove `"format": "uri"` from your schema.